# React Render not working from inside component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm creating a simple React component that updates its own data when a button is clicked. Confusingly, the html is not updated automatically, so I am calling the `render()` function manually. But even that does not update the html. How do I tell react to re-render the component?

```
class Ideas extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.title = "My ideas"
  }

  changeIdeas(){
    this.title = "No more ideas for today"

    // how to re-render the new title? This is not working
    this.render()

    // also not working
    ReactDOM.render(<Ideas/>, window.root)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.title}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.changeIdeas}>Change ideas</button> 
      </div>                          
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Ideas/>, window.root);
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving it as an instance variable, you need to store the title on the state. This will make sure that the variable is tracked by React and the component will be properly updated when it is changed.

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = { title: "My ideas" }
}

changeIdeas = () => {
  this.setState({
    title: "No more ideas for today"
  });
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.changeIdeas}>Change ideas</button> 
      </div>                          
    )
  }
```

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to be working. I also tried using `this.setState({ title: "No more ideas" });` but still nothing is re-rendering....

Comment: @Kokodoko I'e updates the answer with `changeIdeas` example.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the `changeIdeas = () => {}` syntax is needed for methods, instead of regular class method syntax, when using React components. Although, the `render()` method does not need this extra arrow?

Comment: It's an arrow method declaration: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. It ensure proper `this` binding. As alternative you can bind `this` manually: `onClick={this.changeIdeas.bind(this)}`.

Comment: Yeah, but regular ES6 classes bind `this` automatically `class Car { drive(console.log(this)} }`, so I was surprised that React classes don't do this.

Comment: This is not React-specific, this is how ES6 classes work in general.

Comment: No, if you try my `car` example you will see that `console.log(this)` will refer to the car instance, so you don't need the extra `=> {}` in the `drive()` method.

Comment: @Kokodoko For events `this` refers to `window` if you don’t bind to the class explicitly. Also this happens because you are passing a handler to onClick that gets called by the event indirectly. Which is unlike the example you are referring to in your example where the method is called directly. That is why bind is needed. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Yeah you are right! The scope confusion comes from the button event handler. I just noticed that the React tutorial uses the arrow notation inside the button click handler. That way, the class methods don't need the extra arrow (that just looks ugly in my opinion :)  `<button onClick={() => this.changeIdeas()}>Change ideas</button>`